# Delphi strange inaccessible value (acess violation) o.O

Tags: delphi

[image: Self is set but Self.Img inaccessible]

Self contains Img but Self.Img is inaccessible

Comment: Would you mind editing the post to include the uncropped image, or at least the top of it?  Being able to see the top of the call stack is relevant here.

Comment: Looking at those pointers it looks that `Self == Img`.

Comment: @TLama: No, it looks like Self *contains* Img.  That's what the parens mean.

Comment: @Mason, ah, of course... It's even expanded in the object tree.

Comment: was Img created by TPeson at TPerson constructor?

Comment: Yes, Img was created inside constructor, why?

Comment: Please can you accept one of the answers. Your question was answered. I rolled back the question to remove the code you added. Since the question contained no code, it can only be taken to be about the inaccessible value message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What "Inaccessible value" means is that the reference to this value is not valid, and would give an access violation if dereferenced, which the title of your post seems to indicate is what is happening.

Is this debug data showing values from before the access violation was raised, or after it?  Having an exception raised can really screw up what the debugger shows at the top of the call stack, and data from the top few frames should not be trusted.

If this is before the exception was raised, that means you've got corrupt data somewhere.  Is there only one (or a small number of) TPerson object(s) being created? If so, you can put a breakpoint in the constructor and set a [data breakpoint](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Add_Address_Breakpoint_or_Add_Data_Breakpoint) on the Img field, and it'll break when the value changes, which will help you track down the corruption.

Comment: Rather than corruption, more like this is a stale reference to an already destroyed object.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A dangling reference to a previously-existing object would still be pointing into a valid area of the address space.  You wouldn't see "Inaccessible value" then; you'd see garbage data.

Comment: That is not necessarily the case. The memory manager does give memory back to the system. In my experience dangling pointer is way more common than corrupted pointer. You should not fall in to the trap of believing that dangling pointers will not lead to access violations.

Comment: @David - Mason's point is that the pointer would still be pointing to the old *valid* address. Valid being the address itself here, not what the memory there contains

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That's my point. Mason is asserting that the reason why we have *inaccessible value* is that something is corrupting the pointer `Img`. That is one explanation. The other explanation is that the pointer is not being corrupted, but that the address, which was formerly valid, is no longer valid, because the object there has been destroyed.

Comment: @David - That address is at the very top of the 2GB maximum space for a regular 32 bit process in default OS settings. I find it very unlikely it can be valid

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Maybe so. I'm offering the view that corruption is not the only way for a memory address to be invalid. Mason's upvoted comment is factually incorrect.

Comment: @David - Can a dangling pointer be nil for instance? $00000000 is an invalid area of the address space for a pointer.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You know the answer to that question.

Comment: THE IMG WAS CREATED IN THE CSONSTRUCTOR AND THE TPERSON.MOVETO METHOD  IS CALLED FROM TPERSONLIST.MOVETO THAT HAS A POINTER POINTING HIMSELF, I TRADED THE POINTER TO A ARRAY AND THE CODE  WORKED PERFECTLY (SORRY ENGLISH)

Comment: @Jesse - Your caps-lock have been stuck.

Comment: @Jesse Please feel free to accept Mason's answer to your question. Discussions of code are not pertinent because there is no code in this question.

Answer (score 5):

*Inaccessible value* in a watch can mean one of two things, in my experience:

1. A value that cannot be evaluated because of, for instance, an access violation, or
2. A value that cannot be evaluated by the debugger because of insufficient debug information, optimization or similar.

The first explanation would tally with you seeing an access violation. Indeed, I tried to re-create your scenario with this code:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TMyClass = class
    Img: TComponent;
    procedure foo;
  end;

procedure TMyClass.foo;
begin
  Img := TComponent($deadbeef);
end;

begin
  TMyClass.Create.foo;
end.
```

I set a break point after the assignment to `Img` in `TMyClass.foo`, and the watch list looked like this:

[image]

So all the indications are that, in your code, `Img` points to inaccessible memory.

The debugger will be able to confirm this for you. If the line that you have broken executes and produces an access violation then either `Self` or `Self.Img` is invalid. The evidence is that `Self` is fine. But you should be able to debug this without much trouble.